# Matching objects in arrays with non-unique "keys"

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am attempting to match up some values using keys that appear in two arrays. The keys are not unique and can appear multiple times in each array. I want to match them up based on the order in which the occur in the sets array. Below is where I am at right now:

```js
var master = [{name: 'title1', value: 1}, {name: 'title1', value: 2}, {name: 'title2', value: 10}, {name: 'title3', value: 11}];

var sets = [{titles: ['title1', 'title2'], index: 1}, {titles: ['title1', 'title3'], index: 2}];


for (var x = 0; x < sets.length; x++) {
    var set = sets[x];
 for (var i = 0; i < set.titles.length; i++) {
        var title = set.titles[i];
        var real_index = 
        var value = master.filter(function(o){return o.name == title;})[real_index]
        console.log("set: " + set.index + " title: " + title + " value: " + value.value);
    };
}

/*
looking for console output to be:
set: 1 title: title1 value: 1
set: 1 title: title2 value: 10
set: 2 title: title1 value: 2
set: 2 title: title3 value: 11
*/
```

So, essentially I need the variable "real_index" to correspond to the object in the master array, but only use each master array object once. Assume the master array is immutable.

I've attempted to make real_index = 0, but that makes it return the first elements each time (clearly). I've tried to make real_index = x - 1, but that doesn't work for title3, for example. A little stumped.

Additional details:
-In the sets array, titles can appear in more than one set, but they may not appear in any single set more than once.
-In production the master array will be extremely large, and will be used multiple times, so assume that copying/transforming it will not be reasonably accomplished.

Comment: Why not just transform your `master` array into a dictionary keyed off the `name`? Something like: `{ title1: [1,2], title2: [10], title3:[11] }` and remove items from the arrays as you use them.

Comment: yes, I had thought of that, but the master array will get quite large in production, and I'm looking for a more elegant solution. As I will have to run the transform code multiple times. (the master array is used in other parts of the code). Wondering if there is a more concise way of doing it.

Comment: `but the master array will get quite large in production` and you think searching the entire array to match keys is a better solution? It depends on how often you need to access is, but it might be worth the one time cost of a transformation for quicker lookups.

Comment: Do you build the `sets` array? If so, `titles` could be a list of objects (directly referencing the objects in master) rather than a list of strings.

Comment: @CDelaney, no it's coming from an ajax request. As is master array.

Comment: @MattBurland I was under the assumption that the builtin filter function would be about as efficient as returning values by key from a large dictionary... maybe I'm incorrect there.

Comment: @MatthewGraves: The filter function is going to search the entire array to see which items match your condition. It's O(n). Grabbing values from the dictionary should be O(1), but the cost of transforming your array into a dictionary is obviously greater. So it's a question of how many lookups you might need to do versus how long it would take to transform your array.

Answer (score 0):

If master is really long you should go only once through master and for each one look in sets.

```
var master = [{name: 'title1', value: 1}, {name: 'title1', value: 2}, {name: 'title2', value: 10}, {name: 'title3', value: 11}];

var sets = [{titles: ['title1', 'title2'], index: 1}, {titles: ['title1', 'title3'], index: 2}];


for (var x = 0; x < master.length; x++) {
    var value = master[x];
    var sets_in = sets.filter(function(o){return o.titles.indexOf(value.name) !== -1;})
    for (var i = 0; i < sets_in.length; i++) {
        console.log("set: " + sets_in[i].index + " title: " + value.name + " value: " + value.value);
    }
}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/rgtdbo40/

Is this what you are looking for? Does the order mutters?

Comment: The order does matter, and it seems your solution creates extra iterations. We should only have iterations equaling the sum of the titles arrays in sets. In my example case it is 4. Your code results in 12 console logs.

Comment: Sorry, I missunderstood. Is this fiddle more accurate? https://jsfiddle.net/qje5zhs0/

Answer (score 0):

Well this is what I came up with. I really didn't want to deal with a dictionary. I'll need to benchmark both solutions though to see what performance implications, if any, there are.

```js
var master = [{name: 'title1', value: 1}, {name: 'title1', value: 2}, {name: 'title2', value: 10}, {name: 'title3', value: 11}];

var sets = [{titles: ['title1', 'title2'], index: 1}, {titles: ['title1', 'title3'], index: 2}];


for (var x = 0; x < sets.length; x++) {
    var set = sets[x];
 for (var i = 0; i < set.titles.length; i++) {
        var title = set.titles[i];
        var real_index = sets.filter(function(o){return o.titles.indexOf(title) != -1;}).map(function(o){return o.index;}).indexOf(set.index);
        var value = master.filter(function(o){return o.name == title;})[real_index]
        console.log("set: " + set.index + " title: " + title + " value: " + value.value);
    };
}
```